# How i can retain the filter value of datable after answering any dialog or coming back from any page to datable in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, managed-bean

my XHTML page

```
<p:dataTable id="idAlertsTable" widgetVar="idAlertsTable" var="alertRow"
                    value="#{alertsListBean.searchResult }"

                     filterEvent="enter" >

<p:column id="claimYear" sortBy="#{alertRow.claimYear}" filterBy="#{alertRow.claimYear}">                  
            <h:outputText value="#{alertRow.claimYear}" />
</p:column>

<p:column              
            other columns..
</p:column>
```

I have bean for above datatable which is view scoped but I have to store this filterBy value in session,i tried using following thing to store filterBy values & setting it back to Datatable after coming back from any dialog or page

```
  private void setFiltersInSession()
{
    DataTable table = DataTable();--method for getting table
    Map<String,Object> dataTableFilter=(Map<String, Object>)table.getFilters();
    if(!dataTableFilter.isEmpty())
        SessionUtil.setFacesSessionObject("ListFilter", dataTableFilter);
}



private void getFiltersFromSession()
{
    DataTable table = DataTable();
    table.setFilters((Map<String, Object>)SessionUtil.getFacesSessionObject("ListFilter"));
}
```

but when I set it back I lose the values in the filter field of DataTable.how should I do it ?

Comment: what does your viewscoped controller not do for you?

Comment: viewscopedbean is not able to retain the value of filterBy field as I switch back to datatable from any dialog or any other page

Comment: @BalusC:Please help